# Looking for definitive way to enable ALL QGIS module access in VS Code (Windows 10)

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, installation, visual-studio-code

I'm having trouble importing and getting code inspection/autocompletion working for all the PyQGIS modules I need to do scripting in VS Code.  After looking at these questions:

- [Understanding qgis.core import error: no module named qgis.core?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256023/understanding-qgis-core-import-error-no-module-named-qgis-core?rq=1)
- [Importing qgis.core when writing standalone PyQGIS script](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/129959/problem-with-import-qgis-core-when-writing-a-stand-alone-pyqgis-script)
- [Using PyQGIS functions outside QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/385395/using-pyqgis-functions-outside-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [Defining PyCharm to understand PyQGIS and GDAL](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245394/how-to-define-pycharm-to-understand-pyqgis-and-gdal?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [QGIS Intellisense in Visual Studio Code](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/304105/qgis-intellisense-in-visual-studio-code)

I see this is a super common issue.  These helped me move the needle a bit but can't seem to find a definitive answer on what exactly a Windows user needs in a `PYTHONPATH` environment to import all necessary modules from `qgis.core` and `processing`.

**Setup:**

I have QGIS (3.18) installed to `C:\QGIS3` without OSGEO4W.

Using VS Code 1.60.2, which supports a `{workspace}/.env` file to define PYTHONPATH with some precision.

**Problem:**

I have created the `.env` file in the appropriate workspace, and while VS Code is able to import `qgis.core`, it cannot import *from* it (e.g., `QgsProcessing`, `QgsProcessingAlgorithm`, `QgsProcessingParameterFeatureSource`, etc. are all unavailable to me).

I can import from `PyQt5.QtCore` and autocomplete shows `algfactory` as an option when I try to import from `processing`.  So I'm close but not there yet.

Here's what my `.env` file looks like in the workspace:

`PYTHONPATH="C:\QGIS3\apps\Python37;C:\QGIS3\apps\qgis\python;C:\QGIS3\apps\qgis\python\qgis\processing;C:\QGIS3\apps\qgis\python\qgis;C:\QGIS3\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing"`

For easier reading, that's:

- C:\QGIS3\apps\Python37
- C:\QGIS3\apps\qgis\python
- C:\QGIS3\apps\qgis\python\qgis\processing
- C:\QGIS3\apps\qgis\python\qgis
- C:\QGIS3\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing

I'm guessing that some of these paths are unnecessary, but I'm just doing everything I can think of to see what works.  What am I leaving out?

Because I'm running VS Code via gitbash script where I'm doing some general SSL token stuff to negotiate a local gitlab instance, I'd like to stay away from external batch files (so that I can swap quickly between say, PyQGIS, arcpy, and a generic conda FOSS4G environment within the same VS Code session), and would like to be able to do this via the `.env` config file, if possible.

Comment: Are they not available (code does not run) or does VS Code not autocomplete/suggest them?

Comment: @bugmenot123 I put a few import calls in a `try` and it didn't throw errors, but I'm not sure why pylance is not picking up on the autocomplete (which is why one would use VS Code to work with PyQGIS in the first place, presumably).

Comment: Any update on this issue from your side @auslander?

Comment: @Riccardo Nope.  Honestly, I gave up on QGIS scripting.  It just doesn't have much of a place in our Esri-heavy work environment and I couldn't justify the time and friction involved with getting it running.  (Though I do still use the QGIS app itself for occasional one-off things).